# text! within requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Lately I see often 'text!' within requireJS modules - an example below:

```
define(['text!./awesome.hbs'], function(template) {
  return {
    initialize: function() {
      this.html(template);
    }
  };
});
```

what does it stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is used to require text (obviously ) so you can treat none js files as dependencies  , for example template files , which is also the most common use case  .

> It is nice to build HTML using regular HTML tags, instead of building
>   up DOM structures in script. However, there is no good way to embed
>   HTML in a JavaScript file. The best that can be done is using a string
>   of HTML, but that can be hard to manage, particularly for multi-line
>   HTML. RequireJS has a plugin, text.js, that can help with this issue.
>   It will automatically be loaded if the text! prefix is used for a
>   dependency. See the text.js README for more information.

here is the link for the project

https://github.com/requirejs/text

Answer (score 0):

`text!` is the prefix of a plugin of Require JS, called text. See its webpage [here](https://github.com/requirejs/text).

Basically, it loads the resource specified as text:

```
define(['text!./awesome.hbs'], function(template) {
  //template will be a text with the content of the 'awesome.hbs' file
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the 'text' plugin for requireJS:

https://github.com/requirejs/text

It's often used by developers to load template resources into their code but can also be used for general text file resources. The "text!" part tells requireJS to use the text plugin, the file name that follows is loaded in.

Comment: The reason for down voting? I posted this almost simultaneously with Hussein's answer. Strategic down vote?